# Migrating live wordpress to local xampp error

Tags: wordpress, migration

I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcN8eGOxWzk) on how to migrate a live wordpress site to localhost.

I was semi-successful in that when I open the site locally, it appears to be the exact replica of live site.

However, I encountered two issues.

1) When I try to log into wordpress dashboard on local host, it takes me back to live-server dashboard

2) When I click anywhere on the local site, it takes me back to the live site.

Any advice would be appreciated as I have been trying to migrate the site for weeks now,

Thanks

Comment: Just use [Duplicator](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/). It usually doesn't take me more than a few minutes to create a local clone of a live site and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that your database needs updating to reflect the URL change.  Via PHPmyadmin, find your database, go to wp_options and update "siteurl" and "home" to reflect your local URL.

Comment: Can you accept as an official answer? helps my reputation grow.

Answer (score 0):

A alternative to solve the problem is to export the local  database with phpmyadmin in an ascii file and with Notepad++ "Search and replace" fix the urls to show the local host.

Amother alternative it whould be, if you have small site, to usr plugin Duplicator , this produce 2 files an install.pho and a zip. You must take the export from web and then erase tle local and rectreate runing http://localhost/mywp/installer.php. This procedure is going to make everything auto.